# generate anisotropic data in sklearn

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, gaussian

In sklearn documentation, they provide code to convert a blob of normally distributed data to anisotripically distributed data as shown below

```
transformation = [[0.60834549, -0.63667341], [-0.40887718, 0.85253229]]
X_aniso = np.dot(X, transformation)
```

link to the code [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_assumptions.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-kmeans-assumptions-py)

I am wondering what is the function corresponding to th entries in the transformation matrix. Or in general how can one convert as isotropic Gaussian blobs to anisotripic ?

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function is some kind of [linear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix), you can get the concrete angle and scale of the operations using formulae described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78137/decomposition-of-a-nonsquare-affine-matrix).

If you want to make a blob anisotropic you need to shear it along one dimension to transform it into some kind of an ellipsoid.

E.g. in 2D:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(10, 5))

n_samples = 1500
random_state = 170
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=n_samples,
                  random_state=random_state, center_box=(0, 20))
ax1.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y)
ax1.set_title('default')


theta = np.radians(60)
t = np.tan(theta)
shear_x = np.array(((1, t), (0, 1))).T


X_rotated = X.dot(shear_x)
ax2.scatter(X_rotated[:, 0], X_rotated[:, 1], c=y)
ax2.set_title('%1.f degrees X shearing' % np.degrees(theta))


theta = np.radians(70)
t = np.tan(theta)

shear_y = np.array(((1, 0), (t, 1))).T

X_rotated = X.dot(shear_y)
ax3.scatter(X_rotated[:, 0], X_rotated[:, 1], c=y)
ax3.set_title('%1.f degrees Y shearing' % np.degrees(theta))
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]